# Getting real / physical / hardware samplig rate of sound card

Tags: c++, .net, winapi, directx, directsound

I need to get real / physical / hardware (don't know the word) samplig rate of my soundcard.
I'm generating High frequency square sound wave and playing it using DirectSound.

I need to match DirectSound sampling rate with the sound-card.
I don't want windows mixer to re sample my sound because output wave will be totally unusable.

In short: How to get sound-card native sample rate?

Comment: @user980058 You really don't know what your talking about. Frequency can't damage hearing. Only amplitude. Anyway. I'm using that soundwave for my stroboscope, it is not connected to speakers.